# Carthage build a framework containing an inner framework dependency

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios8-extension, carthage

I have a framework target with an inner dependency of another framework target.

So something like:
[image]

The scheme for the outer framework is "shared"

[image]

When I run the command

`carthage build --no-skip-current`

The architecture for the "outer" framework is :

> ~/Developer/Testing/FrameworkTesting/Carthage/Build/iOS : lipo -info
> FrameworkTesting.framework/FrameworkTesting  Architectures in the fat
> file: FrameworkTesting.framework/FrameworkTesting are: i386 x86_64
> armv7 arm64

But the inner framework is only arm:

> ~/Developer/Testing/FrameworkTesting/Carthage/Build/iOS : lipo -info
> FrameworkTesting.framework/Frameworks/InnerFramework.framework/InnerFramework
> Architectures in the fat file:
> FrameworkTesting.framework/Frameworks/InnerFramework.framework/InnerFramework
> are: armv7 arm64

So if I try to use this framework in another project I can not compile.

Should I be doing something to make this work?

P.S.
I also have other frameworks (3rd party) embedded into this framework derived directly from carthage build which also have the same architecture problems.

Comment: Ive outlines 4 workflows concerning using carthage and nested framework: may help? http://stylekit.org/blog/2017/02/03/Carthage-and-nested-frameworks/